# How to detect if Nav has child element using plain Plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

How do I detect if the nav item li has dropdown or not? In the example below:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a> <!-- add class to this LI -->
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Important**

I know this is fair using jQuery - BUT I DONT WANT TO USE JQUERY.

This is the only place where I need JS, I am developing a very clean site where no JavaScript has been used. So just for the shake of this piece I don't want to use jQuery.

**IE8 Compatibility is required though!**

Kindly help on solving this issue using plain JavaScript. thanks all!

Comment: +1 for not wanting to use JQuery, but I am unsure what it is you mean by "the nav item li". Do you want to detect if any of the <li> elements has the dropdown CSS class?

Comment: I want to detect of any li has child element having dropdown class. I will be tweaking styles!

Comment: If you're not using JavaScript anywhere else... can't you just manually add the classes to the original HTML?

Comment: All items are generated by programmer using something like @modal. Those are out of my head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 compatible (but not IE7):

```
var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("#nav .dropdown"), l = qsa.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    qsa[i].parentNode.className = "derp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Kolink*'s answer, you can do the same without using `querySelectorAll` by using `getElementByID` and `getelementsByClassName` (and working for IE7 too):

```
var parent = document.getElementById("nav"),
    childs = parent.getElementsClassName("dropdown"),
    length = childs.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    childs[i].parentNode.className = "derp";
}
```